Xamarin Forms Push Notifications not working
I'm trying to implement push notifications on a xamarin forms application (android version), I know I'll have to update to MAUI, but for now I have to implement it with xamarin forms and Azure Notification Hub, I'm following this tutorial and I've configured azure notification hub with FCM v1, here is my code on Main Activity:
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Listen for push notifications
    NotificationHub.SetListener(new AzureListener());
    // Start the SDK
    NotificationHub.Start(this.Application, Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.ListenConnectionString);
    // Add an event handler
    NotificationHub.Instance.InstanceEvent += OnNotificationMessageReceived;

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());

}

AzureListerner is pretty much the same as the tutorial, here are the versions of nugets packages I'm using
Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android -> 1.1.4.1
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging             -> 122.0.0.2
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base        -> 117.6.0.2

google-services.json is correctly configured, I'm not sure what I'm missing
